# Assigning the line of a file to a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

There are so many answers on the internet! This is what I have done so far:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%config%) do (
    set "s=%%a"
    echo(%s%) // display empty
    echo(%%a) // display a line
)
```

In the loop, I try to assign the line that has been read to a variable. However, it cannot be done. Am I missing something necessary?

Comment: to access %s% immediately you need delayed expansion http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%config%) do (
    set "s=%%a"
    echo(!s!) 
    rem echo(%%a) // display a line
)
endlocal
```

to access %s% immediately you need [delayed expansion](http://%20ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)